# What is meant by subspace clustering in MFA?

Tags: clustering, dimensionality-reduction, statistics

> The basic idea of MFA is to perform **subspace clustering** by assuming the covariance structure for each component of the form, $\Sigma_i = \Lambda_i \Lambda_i^T + \Psi_i$, where $\Lambda_i \in \mathbb{R}^{D\times d}$, is the *factor loadings matrix* with $d < D$ for parsimonious representation of the data, and $Ψ_i$ is the diagonal noise matrix. Note that the mixture of probabilistic principal component analysis (MPPCA) model is a special case of MFA with
> the distribution of the errors assumed to be isotropic with $Ψ_i = Iσ_i^2$.

What is meant by subspace clustering here, and how does $\Sigma_i = \Lambda_i \Lambda_i^T + \Psi_i$ accomplish the same? I understand that this is a dimensionality reduction technique since $\text{rank}(\Lambda_i) \leq d < D$. It'd be great if someone could help me understand more, and/or suggest resources I could look into for learning about this as an *absolute beginner*.

From what I understand, $x = \Lambda z + u$ is *one factor-analyzer* (right?), i.e. the generative model in maximum likelihood factor analysis. [This paper](https://www.cs.toronto.edu/%7Ehinton/absps/tr-96-1.pdf) goes on to define a mixture of factor-analyzers indexed by $\omega_j$, where $j = 1,...,m$. The generative model now obeys the distribution $$P(x) = \sum_{i=1}^m \int P(x|z,\omega_j)P(z|\omega_j)P(\omega_j)dz$$ where, $P(z|\omega_j) = P(z) = \mathcal{N}(0,I)$. **How does this help/achieve the desired objective?** Why take the sum from $1$ to $m$? Where is subspace clustering happening, and what's happening on a high-level when we are using this mixture of factor-analyzers?